# Concerning strong limit cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In the wonderful book Introduction to cardinal arithmetic (Holz, Steffens, Weitz) on the page 78 I have come across the following assertion:

Let $\kappa$ be a singular cardinal. $F$ is a function from $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ into $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$. $a(i)$ is a sequence unbounded in $\kappa$ ($i < \operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$) such that the set $$\{ i < \operatorname{cf}(\kappa) : 2^{a(i)} \leq a(i)^{+F(i)}\}$$ is unbounded in $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$. 
($a(i)^+$ is the successor cardinal of $a(i)$). Then $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal.

I can prove it only assuming that $a(i)$ is not decreasing plus $\kappa$ is $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$-strong. Can anyone prove the assertion without the assumption? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jacmeird: Just putting dollar signs around things is not enough to make it correct. You should perhaps familiarize yourself with the notation before trying to correct it.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $a(i)^{+F(i)}$ (the $F(i)$-th successor of $a(i)$) instead of $(a(i)^+)^{F(i)}$?

Comment: You must be right: otherwise we must demand that every value of F be a cardinal number. OK, if it`s the F(i)-th succesor, then what's the proof?

Comment: @arjafi: Yeah, you're right about the formulation of the problem.

Comment: @arjafi: looks like, now the catch is that the a(i) is not supposed to be not decreasing, so how can I find an upper bound for an arbitrary value of a continuum function in k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true in general without the non-decreasing assumption.

For a counterexample, pick any singular $\kappa$ and let $a(i)=0$ and $F(i)=1$ for all even $i$. This will ensure that $2^{a(i)}\leq a(i)^{+F(i)}$ for these $i$, since $2^0=1=0^+$, and so the collection of $i$ will be unbounded. Now, specify $a(i)$ for odd $i$ to make it unbounded in $\kappa$.

Meanwhile, if one assumes that $a(i)$ is non-decreasing, then indeed $\kappa$ must be a strong limit. To see this, consider any $\delta<\kappa$. Pick some $i$ with $\delta\leq a(i)$ and $2^{a(i)}\leq a(i)^{+F(i)}$. Since $\kappa$ has cofinality $\text{cf}(\kappa)$ and $a(i)<\kappa$, it follows that $a(i)^{+F(i)}<\kappa$. And so $2^\delta<\kappa$, as desired.

Comment: Is the additional condition

Comment: I showed that assuming $a(i)$ is non-decreasing is sufficient, and this is likely what the authors had meant.

Comment: Is the additional condition of not decreasing  of a(i) would suffice? How can I be sure that the F(i)-th successor of a(i) would not ecxeed k?

Comment: Please, clarify why the F(i)-th successor of a(i) less than k. Does it have to do something with addition of ordinals?

Comment: Because $a(i)<\kappa$ and $F(i)$ is less than the cofinality of $\kappa$. You cannot climb from $a(i)$ to $\kappa$ in fewer than $\text{cf}(\kappa)$ steps.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: I cannot climb there because otherwise I would  get a set cofinal in k with cardinality less than cf(k)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you professor Hamkins for your great help.

Comment: Sure thing. By the way, did you know that you can upvote answers and also accept them? This is how one usually expresses appreciation. Click on the uparrow to the left of the answer and on the check button to accept.

Comment: Well, I remedied that.